# What does DispatchWallTime do on iOS?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I thought the difference between DispatchTime and DispatchWallTime had to do with whether the app was suspended or the device screen was locked or something: DispatchTime should pause, whereas DispatchWallTime should keep going because clocks in the real world keep going.

So I wrote a little test app:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("backgrounding the app, starting timers for 60 seconds", Date())
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
            print("deadline 60 seconds ended", Date())
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 60) {
            print("wallDeadline 60 seconds ended", Date())
        }
    }
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("app coming to front", Date())
    }
}
```

I ran the app on my device. I backgrounded the app, waited for a while, then brought the app to the foreground. Sometimes "waited for a while" included switching off the screen. I got results like this:

```
backgrounding the app, starting timers for 60 seconds 2018-08-15 17:41:18 +0000
app coming to front 2018-08-15 17:41:58 +0000
wallDeadline 60 seconds ended 2018-08-15 17:42:24 +0000
deadline 60 seconds ended 2018-08-15 17:42:24 +0000

backgrounding the app, starting timers for 60 seconds 2018-08-15 17:42:49 +0000
app coming to front 2018-08-15 17:43:21 +0000
wallDeadline 60 seconds ended 2018-08-15 17:43:55 +0000
deadline 60 seconds ended 2018-08-15 17:43:55 +0000
```

The delay before the `deadline` timer fires is not as long as I expected: it's 6 seconds over the 60 second deadline, even though I "slept" the app for considerably longer than that. But even more surprising, both timers fire at the same instant.

So what does `wallDeadline` do on iOS that's *different* from what `deadline` does?

Comment: Isn't this have to do with the app suspending itself in the background, based on some *magic*? DispatchTime shouldn't automatically suspend itself immediately after entering the background, at least I can't find anything about that [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtime).

Comment: There is some discussion [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/49361) and from what I can make out, it the difference isn't related to whether the *app* sleeps, but rather if the *system* sleeps. I think it may be that it is more of an issue on macOS where apps aren't suspended

Comment: @Paulw11 Just what I'm wondering. — What I find most curious, though, is that the wall deadline doesn't seem to be capable of watching the clock. It's late. Which is not at all as advertised by the docs.

Comment: I ran a test on macOS as a comparison.  I dispatched the blocks just as you did and then put the Mac to sleep until after the deadline time.  When I woke the Mac I saw that the wall clock deadline executed immediately while the normal deadline was delayed it was not delayed by the full amount of time that the laptop was asleep (based on my looking at the clock when I selected "Sleep" and when I woke the laptop, so probably some inaccuracy there too).  The behaviour seems closer to the documentation on macOS than on iOS

Comment: @Paulw11 My guess is that (a) phones don't sleep and (2) on iOS there is really no such thing as wall time — I think it just falls over to being the same as normal dispatch time.

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been here for quite a while without any answers, so I'd like to give it a try and point out subtle difference I noticed in practice.

> DispatchTime should pause, whereas DispatchWallTime should keep going
> because clocks in the real world keep going

You are correct here, at least they are supposed to work this way. It's really tricky to check that `DispatchTime` suspends, though: when an iOS app is running under Xcode debugging session, it has unlimited background time and isn't getting suspended. Moreover, even when playing around with the app without Xcode connected, I could not confirm that `DispatchTime` is paused under whatever conditions. I found, however, that there is another key property: **`DispatchTime` doesn't depend on the system clock**. **`DispatchWallTime`** works pretty much the same (and I couldn't confirm that it gets paused either), with exception to that it **depends on the system clock**.

In order to see the difference, you can try out a little longer timer, say, 5 minutes. After that go to the system settings and set the time 1 hour forward. If you now open the application you can notice, that `DispatchWallTime` immediately expires whereas `DispatchTime` keeps waiting for its time to come

Answer (score 18):

There's nothing wrong with The Dreams Wind's answer, but I wanted to understand these APIs more precisely. Here's my analysis.

#### `DispatchTime`

Here's the comment above [`DispatchTime.init`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/a5f5a923a4498661e19bfe8411640838b8b9571b/src/swift/Time.swift):

> ```
> /// Creates a `DispatchTime` relative to the system clock that
> /// ticks since boot.
> ///
> /// - Parameters:
> ///   - uptimeNanoseconds: The number of nanoseconds since boot, excluding
> ///                        time the system spent asleep
> /// - Returns: A new `DispatchTime`
> /// - Discussion: This clock is the same as the value returned by
> ///               `mach_absolute_time` when converted into nanoseconds.
> ///               On some platforms, the nanosecond value is rounded up to a
> ///               multiple of the Mach timebase, using the conversion factors
> ///               returned by `mach_timebase_info()`. The nanosecond equivalent
> ///               of the rounded result can be obtained by reading the
> ///               `uptimeNanoseconds` property.
> ///               Note that `DispatchTime(uptimeNanoseconds: 0)` is
> ///               equivalent to `DispatchTime.now()`, that is, its value
> ///               represents the number of nanoseconds since boot (excluding
> ///               system sleep time), not zero nanoseconds since boot.
> ```

So `DispatchTime` is based on `mach_absolute_time`. But what is `mach_absolute_time`? It's defined in [`mach_absolute_time.s`](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a449c6a3b8014d9406c2ddbdc81795da24aa7443/libsyscall/wrappers/mach_absolute_time.s). There is a separate definition for each CPU type, but the key is that it uses `rdtsc` on x86-like CPUs and reads the `CNTPCT_EL0` register on ARMs. In both cases, it's getting a value that **increases monotonically, and only increases while the processor is not in a sufficiently deep sleep state**.

Note that the CPU is not necessarily sleeping deeply enough even if the device appears to be asleep.

#### `DispatchWallTime`

There's no similarly helpful comment in the `DispatchWallTime` definition, but we can look at the definition of its `now` method:

> ```
> public static func now() -> DispatchWallTime {
>     return DispatchWallTime(rawValue: CDispatch.dispatch_walltime(nil, 0))
> }
> ```

and then we can consult [the definition of `dispatch_walltime`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/a5f5a923a4498661e19bfe8411640838b8b9571b/src/time.c):

> ```
> dispatch_time_t
> dispatch_walltime(const struct timespec *inval, int64_t delta)
> {
>   int64_t nsec;
>   if (inval) {
>       nsec = (int64_t)_dispatch_timespec_to_nano(*inval);
>   } else {
>       nsec = (int64_t)_dispatch_get_nanoseconds();
>   }
>   nsec += delta;
>   if (nsec <= 1) {
>       // -1 is special == DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER == forever
>       return delta >= 0 ? DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER : (dispatch_time_t)-2ll;
>   }
>   return (dispatch_time_t)-nsec;
> }
> ```

When `inval` is nil, it calls `_dispatch_get_nanoseconds`, so [let's check that out](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/a5f5a923a4498661e19bfe8411640838b8b9571b/src/shims/time.h):

> ```
> static inline uint64_t
> _dispatch_get_nanoseconds(void)
> {
>   dispatch_static_assert(sizeof(NSEC_PER_SEC) == 8);
>   dispatch_static_assert(sizeof(USEC_PER_SEC) == 8);
>
> #if TARGET_OS_MAC
>   return clock_gettime_nsec_np(CLOCK_REALTIME);
> #elif HAVE_DECL_CLOCK_REALTIME
>   struct timespec ts;
>   dispatch_assume_zero(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts));
>   return _dispatch_timespec_to_nano(ts);
> #elif defined(_WIN32)
>   static const uint64_t kNTToUNIXBiasAdjustment = 11644473600 * NSEC_PER_SEC;
>   // FILETIME is 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).
>   FILETIME ft;
>   ULARGE_INTEGER li;
>   GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&ft);
>   li.LowPart = ft.dwLowDateTime;
>   li.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
>   return li.QuadPart * 100ull - kNTToUNIXBiasAdjustment;
> #else
>   struct timeval tv;
>   dispatch_assert_zero(gettimeofday(&tv, NULL));
>   return _dispatch_timeval_to_nano(tv);
> #endif
> }
> ```

It consults the POSIX `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock. So it is based on the common idea of time and will change if you change your device's time in Settings (or System Preferences on a Mac).

#### The Mysterious Six Seconds

You said your timer fired

> 6 seconds over the 60 second deadline

so let's see where that came from.

Both `asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)` and `asyncAfter(wallDeadline:execute:)` call the same C API, `dispatch_after`. The kind of deadline (or “clock”) is encoded into a `dispatch_time_t` along with the time value. The `dispatch_after` function calls [the internal GCD function `_dispatch_after`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/a5f5a923a4498661e19bfe8411640838b8b9571b/src/source.c), which I quote in part here:

> ```
> static inline void
> _dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t when, dispatch_queue_t dq,
>       void *ctxt, void *handler, bool block)
> {
>   dispatch_timer_source_refs_t dt;
>   dispatch_source_t ds;
>   uint64_t leeway, delta;
> ```

*snip*

> ```
>   delta = _dispatch_timeout(when);
>   if (delta == 0) {
>       if (block) {
>           return dispatch_async(dq, handler);
>       }
>       return dispatch_async_f(dq, ctxt, handler);
>   }
>   leeway = delta / 10; // <rdar://problem/13447496>
>
>   if (leeway < NSEC_PER_MSEC) leeway = NSEC_PER_MSEC;
>   if (leeway > 60 * NSEC_PER_SEC) leeway = 60 * NSEC_PER_SEC;
> ```

*snip*

> ```
>   dispatch_clock_t clock;
>   uint64_t target;
>   _dispatch_time_to_clock_and_value(when, &clock, &target);
>   if (clock != DISPATCH_CLOCK_WALL) {
>       leeway = _dispatch_time_nano2mach(leeway);
>   }
>   dt->du_timer_flags |= _dispatch_timer_flags_from_clock(clock);
>   dt->dt_timer.target = target;
>   dt->dt_timer.interval = UINT64_MAX;
>   dt->dt_timer.deadline = target + leeway;
>   dispatch_activate(ds);
> }
> ```

The `_dispatch_timeout` function can be found in [`time.c`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/time.c). Suffice to say it returns the number of nanoseconds between the current time and the time passed to it. It determines the “current time” based on the clock of the time passed to it.

So `_dispatch_after` gets the number of nanoseconds to wait before executing your block. Then it computes `leeway` as one tenth of that duration. When it sets the timer's deadline, **it adds `leeway` to the deadline you passed in**.

In your case, `delta` is about 60 seconds (= 60 * 10<sup>9</sup> nanoseconds), so `leeway` is about 6 seconds. Hence your block is executed about 66 seconds after you call `asyncAfter`.